Django sorting by Date, Name
I am new in Django, and I want to sort my querys by date or name. I did it but I additonally want to do an option to change it on website. I coudln't find an answer anywhere how to do it. Am I going wrong way?
I tried do do it like that:
{% block content %}
<h1 class="tytul">Lokalizacja plików</h1>
<div class="naglowek">
<div class="card card-body">

<p>Wyszukaj plik</p>
<form method="get">{{myFilter.form}}
<button class="button" type="submit">
    Wyszukaj
</button>
</form>

<div class="sortowanie">Wybierz po czym sortować:
<select class="sort">

    <option>Nazwa</option>

    <option>Data</option>

</select>
</div>
</div>
</div>


HTML



    {% for plik in obj %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="com">
        {{plik.nazwa}}
    </div>
    <div class="com">
        {{plik.data}}
    </div>
    <div class="com">
        {{plik.lokalizacja}} 
    </div>
    <div class="przy">
        <a href="{% url 'download' plik.lokalizacja %} " class="button">pobierz</a>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}

</div>     
{% endblock %}

I am trying to do and option to change sorting by date and name by user

Please provide your views.py code here for better understanding of your query.

You can use query parameters to change the sorting of the query in the view and also have a default value if the user hasn't specified anything. However, the page will refresh once for each request. If you use AJAX, only the questions section will update with each request, which requires some basic knowledge of front-end and JavaScript.

There is no way to do it easy in Django?

i'm not sure about, bعt it's super clear in each request you get  specific date and for another piece of data you should request again or get all type data that is not best practice and efficient

In your view, you have a string sort_by (which possibly arrived from the user as a form's ChoiceField with sort-by strings as the values). Generate your queryset as at present. Then modify it
query = query.order_by( sort_by)

For extremely capable user-controlled filtering and sorting, don't try to roll your own. Learn about django-filter!
